# How do I host a simple html code on kubernetes within our network?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, service-node-port-range

I am trying to host a simple html static site on kubernetes and was able to set everything working as expected but when I used **load balancer** in the service its exposed to public.

I tried to use **nodeport** option but our node dont have public IP to access it.

With just custer IP Iam unable to access it as well.

How do we host site only internally and which approach is the right one.

I started to look in to ingress controllers but then could not ways to install it to use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "within your cluster"? I get that you don't mean inside the internal network of the Pods (which would be ClusterIP)

Comment: I meant internal to our VPN. My understanding is we cannot access cluster IP on our browser. can we?

Comment: Yeah, ClusterIP is for internal cluster networking. I don't know what is your setup, but if you join a VPN, the kubernetes cluster nodes should then be available at their IP address? If yes, then a NodePort should work to reach the http page at one of the cluster IP addresses from inside the vpn?

Comment: HI, I need to agree with the comment made by AndD. For clearer picture of your setup could you please more about it? Is it a cloud managed solution or a on-premise one? Do you have the ability to connect to the `Nodes` directly by your `VPN`? Apart from what AndD suggested, I'd reckon you could deploy the `Ingress` controller with a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` that IP will reside in the "internal" network (`Nodes` network).

Comment: hi @DawidKruk thank you. Its a cloud managed. I dont have ability to connect to nodes. Thanks for the idea I did look in to that option but could not find proper documentation on how to install ingress controller.

Ideally, I am trying to setup more like an  intranet site and looking for ideas on best solutions to host a site internally using kubetnetes.

Comment: @mamidala86 could you please tell which managed solution is it? Is it a `GKE`, `EKS`, `AKS`? As for `Ingress controller` installation (one of many), I'd reckon you can take a look here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to give more of a baseline approach and to point to the possible solutions.

Feel free to edit/expand.

---

Answering the question from the title:

> How do I host a simple html code on kubernetes within our network?

This question is mainly related to the `Services` and how they work. Assuming that you already have a `Deployment` with it, the best course of actions would be to reach to the documentation of your cloud provider on the support of various `Services` and how you can connect to them. In general you would connect to this `Deployment` (with some `html` code) either by:

- `Service` of type `NodePort` - port (`30000`-`32767`) on each `Node` will be opened for accessing the `Deployment`
- `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` - IP address will be requested for the `Service` which you can access to get to the `Deployment` (can be **internal** or external)

---

As this topic is related to cloud-managed solutions and it's requirement is to connect to the `Service` from the network hosted by a cloud-provider, I'd reckon one of the solutions would be to look for objects like:

- *Internal Ingress*
- *Internal LoadBalancer*

This objects will be created in a way that you could access them only from the internal network (which I'm assuming you are connected to with your `VPN`).

Examples of such implementations across some cloud providers:

- `GKE`: *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Internal load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing)*
- `EKS`: *[Docs.aws.amazon.com: Latest: Userguide: Network load balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html)*
- `AKS`: *[Docs.microsoft.com: Azure: AKS: Internal lb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb)*

> A side note!
>
> You can use `Service` of type `Loadbalancer` (internal one) to be the entrypoint for your `Ingress` controller like `ingress-nginx`:
>
> - *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Service networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*